# Standard Operations on Option<T> monad beyond Bind and Map

Tags: c#, functional-programming, monads

I'm using a C# implementation of F# `` option<`a`> `` monad from Petricek book (Real World Functional Programming):

```
internal enum OptionType { Some, None }

internal abstract class Option<T>
{
    private readonly OptionType tag;

    protected Option(OptionType tag)
    {
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    public OptionType Tag
    {
        get { return this.tag; }
    }

    public bool MatchNone()
    {
        return this.Tag == OptionType.None;
    }

    public bool MatchSome(out T value)
    {
        if (this.Tag == OptionType.Some)
        {
            value = ((Some<T>)this).Value;
        }
        else
        {
            value = default(T);
        }
        return this.Tag == OptionType.Some;
    }
}

internal sealed class None<T> : Option<T>
{
    public None() : base(OptionType.None) { }
}

internal sealed class Some<T> : Option<T>
{
    private readonly T value;

    public Some(T value)
        : base(OptionType.Some)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.value;
        }
    }
}

internal static class Option
{
    public static Option<T> None<T>()
    {
        return new None<T>();
    }

    public static Some<T> Some<T>(T value)
    {
        return new Some<T>(value);
    }
}

internal static class OptionExtensions
{
    public static Option<T2> Bind<T1, T2>(this Option<T1> option, Func<T1, Option<T2>> func)
    {
        T1 value1;
        if (option.MatchSome(out value1))
        {
            return func(value1);
        }
        return Option.None<T2>();
    }

    public static Option<T2> Map<T1, T2>(this Option<T1> option, Func<T1, T2> func)
    {
        T1 value1;
        if (option.MatchSome(out value1))
        {
            return Option.Some(func(value1));
        }
        return Option.None<T2>();
    }
}
```

**Now I need an operation to extract the value if it's not `None` or returns a default.**

I was wondering if this is possible using a combination of `Map` and `Bind`, but I think is not.

So I'm back to [F# documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233245.aspx), it gave me hints on some other useful extension methods to add, but not exactly what I need.

I've designed this function to fulfill my need:

```
public static T2 Return<T1, T2>(this Option<T1> option, Func<T1, T2> func, T2 noneValue)
{
    T1 value1;
    if (option.MatchSome(out value1))
    {
        return func(value1);
    }
    return noneValue;
}
```

So to not reinvent the wheel, the question is: is there's a reference or common functional patterns to define operations on `Option<T>` monad? *Is correct add new operations on need?*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A monad where you can always extract a value is usually a *comonad*.  You know that a monad `M<T>` has methods (in C# syntax)

```
static M<T> Unit<T>(T t) { ... }
static M<R> Bind<A, R>(M<A> ma, Func<A, M<R>> func) { ... }
```

Or, alternatively, you can make a monad out of

```
static M<T> Unit<T>(T t) { ... }
static M<R> FMap<A, R>(M<A> ma, Func<A, R> func) { ... }
static M<T> Join<T>(M<M<T>> mmt) { ... }
```

The two characterizations are equivalent; you can construct one given implementations of the other.

A comonad has operations

```
static T Extract<T>(M<T> mt) { ... } 
static M<R> Extend<A, R>(M<A> ma, Func<M<A>, R> func) { ... }
```

Extract is the "opposite" of Unit and Extend is the "opposite" of Bind.

Alternatively, you can also define a comonad with these operations:

```
static T Extract<T>(M<T> mt) { ... } 
static M<R> FMap<A, R>(M<A> ma, Func<A, R> func) { ... }
static M<M<T>> Duplicate<T>(M<T> mt) { ... }
```

Where Duplicate is the "opposite" of Join. Again, the two characterizations are equivalent; given one, you can build the other.

Clearly you cannot implement Extract only given Bind, Unit, FMap and Join, because *none of those in any way return a T*, and its a T that you need.

With either version of comonads, the problem you're running into is that the optional monad really isn't a comonad because there's no natural way to implement Extract if the monadic value is "missing".

Now, you can do what `Nullable<T>` does if you want. `Nullable<T>.GetValueOrDefault()` returns the value if there is one and `default(T)` if there isn't. That's probably the best you can do here if you want to make Optional into a comonad.

Comment: +1 and this answers very clearly to my question. Appreciated also the terminology (_comonad_) clarification.

Comment: @jay: You're welcome. I have recently written a series of thirteen posts on my blog that discuss monads for the C# programmer. Check it out if that subject interests you. http://ericlippert.com/category/monads

Comment: thanks Eric. I'm already a reader of this and other series on your blog. This last about ``monads``, I've to say it's really interesting. :)